# Understanding usages of would

Tags: will-would

> I **would** call you.

What does this mean?

1) Am I being **doubtful about calling** someone? 
 Like less probability of calling someone.

2) Just saying that I **will call** if some conditions happen.
Like in conditional sentences such as: *if my mobile had charge, I would call you*.

Answer (score 0):

"I would call you" could mean different things, depending on the context.

You wouldn't use it to express *doubt* as such, although you could use it to indicate a *condition* for it happening, for example:

> I would call you *if* I had a phone.

You could also use it with a possible reason why you would not, for example:

> I would call you *but* I don't have a phone.

You might say "I would call you" without a condition or exception if you were answering a hypothetical question, for example:

> Q. What would you do if you had a phone?
>   A. I would call you.

In spoken English, the inflexion you put on the word would help determine what you meant. Your tone would either express certainty or uncertainty.